# Junit/other - email testing

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, junit

I am working on a project that is built on Java and sends some email to legacy systems, at the moment in the dev env we are using gmail to test the emails.

I wanted to ask that if there is any existing test framework that can hook up to the mail/exchange server and perform the test that if the email are getting sent correctly and have the content is correct. or similar or if there is a workaround for that. Also, the content of the emails is dynamically generated.

I checked out the other question before I posted this question... but none seems to be an answer to my question

Comment: would https://mailsnag.com work for that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Dumbster](http://quintanasoft.com/dumbster/)?

If this doesn't meet your criteria, then see the other answers to [Running Junit Email Tests Without Emails Actually Going Out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027595/running-junit-email-tests-without-emails-actually-going-out)