# How can I create an empty IMAPMessage without having a connection to an Email server?

Tags: java

I need a IMAPMessage for test purposes. How can I get an empty one in Java?

Something like:

```
IMAPMessage imapm = new IMAPMessage(mimeMessage, messageNumber);
```

The idea is not to create one without having a valid session.

Comment: Try to use  a [fake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027595/running-junit-email-tests-without-emails-actually-going-out) mail server. GreenMail was mentioned there.

Comment: Works ok with GreenMail. Thanks.